# Is the value of the integral rational?

Tags: number-theory, definite-integrals

What is the value of the following integration

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{2\pi x}-1}{e^{2\pi x}+1}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}\right)dx$$

Here $n$ is a positive integer.

I have no idea how to calculate this integral. Please help.

Comment: Are you expecting an answer in closed form?  If so, why?

Comment: This was a programming competition problem a few months ago. Is this another active competition?

Comment: Just corrected. mistakes im my solution :)

Comment: Please all do not answer this question. I believe it is from an active contest.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is from an ongoing contest.

Comment: @K.defaoite Just deleted.